# Determining the percent overshoot, settling time, and peak time of a transfer function

Tags: control-system, transfer-function

I'm finding the percent overshoot, settling time, and peak time of the rotational mechanical system below. I'm worried that these variables may be undertermined.

[image]

I've found that the two equations are:
$$(2s^{2}+s)\Theta_{1}(s)-s\Theta_{2}(s)=T(s)$$
$$-s\Theta_{1}(s)+(s+1)\Theta_{2}(s)=0$$

Solving for the transfer function,
$$\frac{\Theta_{2}(s)}{T(s)}=\frac{1}{2s^{2}+2s+1}$$

Next, based on the transfer function above, I obtained both the undamped natural frequency and damping ratio to be 1. This gave me problems in solving for the %OS and the rest. The formula for %OS, after all, is \$percent overshoot=e^{-\frac{\zeta \pi }{\sqrt{1-\zeta ^{2}}}}\times 100 \$. The denominator would definitely be zero after substituting those values.

Furthermore, I think these answers support the following graph:[image]

What do you think? Where did I go wrong?

Comment: What if I get different values for \$\zeta\$ and \$\omega_{_0}\$ assuming your transfer function is accurate?

Comment: Please add the detailed calculations on how you got damping ratio to be `1`. I got a different number. Perhaps you didn't rewrite the denominator so that coefficient of `s^2` is `1`.